# Get stdout from other program in Linux

Tags: linux, process, stdout

I want in *Linux*, get the *stdout*  of a *NodeJS* program that is opened, from other *NodeJS* program or *bash*.

I have the *PID*, or name of program and the data, put to function in real time.

Maybe touching files in `/proc`?

This is possible?

Comment: You can use `strace -e write -p <pid>` to see what output is the program writing to stdout (or other FDs) in real time. But it does not show what has been written earlier and it needs a little parsing to extract clean stdout contents.

Comment: @RomanHocke Works correctly, but show parcial `stdout`.

Comment: Try using `-s` switch. For example `strace -e write -s 9999 -p <pid>`. Check documentation for other possibly useful switches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strace -e write -p <pid>` to see what output is the program writing to stdout (or other FDs) in real time. It does not show what has been written earlier and it needs a little parsing to extract clean stdout contents.

By default, it truncates shown writes to only 32 characters. To show more, use `-s` switch:

```
strace -e write -s 9999 -p <pid>
```